# Como extrair o texto entre parênteses com regex em php

Tags: php, regex

Tenho o texto:

As expressões regulares (muitas vezes abreviado para "regex") são uma linguagem declarativa utilizada para correspondência.

Como faço para pegar o conteúdo incluído entre os parênteses?

Tentei:

```
$texto = "As expressões regulares (muitas vezes abreviado para "regex") são uma linguagem declarativa utilizada para correspondência." ;
preg_match("/\(*\)/", $texto, $testando);
var_dump($testando) ;
```

A saída é:

```
array (size=1)
   0 => string ')' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faltou especificar qual caracter quer casa na sua regex, no caso o ponto `.`. Ou seja vai pegar um parentese seguido de qualquer coisa `.*` seguido de um fechamento de parentese.

```
$texto = "As expressões regulares (muitas vezes abreviado para 'regex') são uma linguagem declarativa utilizada para correspondência." ;
preg_match("/\(.*\)/", $texto, $testando);
var_dump($testando) ;
```

Ou para pegar o contúdo dentro dos dois parênteses, use a função `preg_match_all()`, mude a regex para combinar letras e números (`\w`), caracteres como espaço, tab e outros (`\s`) e aspa simples (`'`)

```
$texto = "As expressões regulares (muitas vezes abreviado para 'regex') são uma linguagem (declarativa utilizada) para correspondência";
preg_match_all("#\([\w\s']+\)#i", $texto, $testando);
var_dump($testando) ;
```

Comment: No caso em: $texto = "As expressões regulares (muitas vezes abreviado para 'regex') são uma linguagem (declarativa utilizada) para correspondência." Conseguiria trazer os 2 trechos entre parênteses separadamente?

Comment: @Taisbevalle, obrigado!
Funcionou direitinho.
A resposta agora foi **(muitas vezes abreviado para 'regex')**

Comment: Resta resolver o problema citado pelo @GivanildoR.deOliveira. Quando há duas sequências "654321(GGG) blá (HSH)123456"  o retorno é "(GGG) BLÁ (HSH)" enquanto o desejável seria "(GGG)" e "(HSH)"

Comment: @GivanildoR.deOliveira editei a resposta.

Comment: Fantástico @rray.